# Unable to set a initial page in php codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, frameworks, base-url

I'm new in php codeigniter, i need to modify a project but i cant set the base url it redirects me to an external url and i can't edit anything in the project.

for example if I enter the project path, it redirects me to 'https://test.com'

I set the base url in application/config to localhost. But it does not work.
this is my base url

```
$config['base_url'] = 'localhost/';
```

I have no idea what else could cause this problem I am very frustrated

Any idea or solution will be aprecciated.

Have a good day

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing, when you try the below you always get the value https://test.com?
You can search the project folder for that value if it is being overriden somewhere.

```
<?php echo base_url(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try check the `.htaccess` file under your codeigniter file project maybe your `.htaccess` set the url like this :

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://test.com/$1 [R,L]
```

change it to

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://localhost/yourfilename/$1 [R,L]
```